# Post Data to Google Analytics through requests

Tags: python, google-analytics, python-requests

I'm trying to post data into GA, but I'm getting a indexing error
The connection is working as I'm getting response 200, but there seems to be a problem with the for loop which posts all the rows from my dataframe. Anyone who could please help me? thanks!

```
endpoint = 'http://www.google-analytics.com/collect'

payload1 = {
                   'v'     : "1",
                   't'     : "event",
                   'pa'    : "purchase",
                   'tid'   : "xxx",
                   'cid'   : df.iloc[i,0],
                   'ti'    : df.iloc[i,6],
                   'ec'    : "ecommerce",
                   'ea'    : "transaction",
                   'ta'    : "aaaa",
                   'tr'    : df.iloc[i,17],
                   'cd1'   : df.iloc[i,0],
                   'cd2'   : df.iloc[i,6],

                   'cu'    : "bbb",
                   "pr1id" : "ccc",
                   'pr1nm' : "ddd",
                   'pr1pr' : df.iloc[i,17],
                   'pr1qt' : 1,
                   'cs'    : "offline"

                      }





for i in df.iterrows():

    r = requests.post(url = endpoint ,

                      data  = payload1,


                      headers={'User-Agent': 'User 1.0'})
    time.sleep(0.1) 
    print(r)
```

Error:

> ---
>
> IndexingError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
>        in 
>             4                    'pa'    : "purchase",
>             5                    'tid'   : "xxx",
>       ----> 6                    'cid'   : df.iloc[i,0],
>             7                    'ti'    : df.iloc[i,6],
>             8                    'ec'    : "ecommerce",
>
> ~\path\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py in **getitem**(self, key)
>          1416                 except (KeyError, IndexError, AttributeError):
>          1417                     pass
>       -> 1418             return self._getitem_tuple(key)
>          1419         else:
>          1420             # we by definition only have the 0th axis
>
> ~\path\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py in _getitem_tuple(self, tup)
>          2090     def _getitem_tuple(self, tup):
>          2091 
>       -> 2092         self._has_valid_tuple(tup)
>          2093         try:
>          2094             return self._getitem_lowerdim(tup)
>
> ~\path\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py in _has_valid_tuple(self, key)
>           233                 raise IndexingError("Too many indexers")
>           234             try:
>       --> 235                 self._validate_key(k, i)
>           236             except ValueError:
>           237                 raise ValueError(
>
> ~\path\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py in _validate_key(self, key, axis)
>          2016             # a tuple should already have been caught by this point
>          2017             # so don't treat a tuple as a valid indexer
>       -> 2018             raise IndexingError("Too many indexers")
>          2019         elif is_list_like_indexer(key):
>          2020             arr = np.array(key)
>
> IndexingError: Too many indexers

Answer (score 0):

`df.iterrows()` will return the [row index and the row itself](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iterrows.html) as a pandas series in each loop.  You can then get the row value using the name of the column, if that's easier.

Try instead (I'm guessing the names of the columns):

```py
endpoint = 'http://www.google-analytics.com/collect'
for ind, row in df.iterrows():

    r = requests.post(url = endpoint ,
           data  = {
                   'v'     : "1",
                   't'     : "event",
                   'pa'    : "purchase",
                   'tid'   : "xxx",
                   'cid'   : row["cid"],
                   'ti'    : row["ti"],
                   'ec'    : "ecommerce",
                   'ea'    : "transaction",
                   'ta'    : "aaaa",
                   'tr'    : row["tr"],
                   'cd1'   : row["cd1"],
                   'cd2'   : row["cd2"],
                   'cu'    : "bbb",
                   "pr1id" : "ccc",
                   'pr1nm' : "ddd",
                   'pr1pr' : row['pr1pr'],
                   'pr1qt' : 1,
                   'cs'    : "offline"
                      },
                      headers={'User-Agent': 'User 1.0'
                    }
    )
    time.sleep(0.1) 
    print(r.text)
```

It's more common to do this sort of operation using the [apply function in pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html):

```py
endpoint = 'http://www.google-analytics.com/collect'
def sendRowToGA(row):
    r = requests.post(url = endpoint ,
           data  = {
                   'v'     : "1",
                   't'     : "event",
                   'pa'    : "purchase",
                   'tid'   : "xxx",
                   'cid'   : row["cid"],
                   'ti'    : row["ti"],
                   'ec'    : "ecommerce",
                   'ea'    : "transaction",
                   'ta'    : "aaaa",
                   'tr'    : row["tr"],
                   'cd1'   : row["cd1"],
                   'cd2'   : row["cd2"],
                   'cu'    : "bbb",
                   "pr1id" : "ccc",
                   'pr1nm' : "ddd",
                   'pr1pr' : row['pr1pr'],
                   'pr1qt' : 1,
                   'cs'    : "offline"
                      },
                      headers={'User-Agent': 'User 1.0'
                    }
    )
    print(r.text)


df.apply(sendRowToGA, axis = 1)
```

Comment: I'm happy it was useful, would you consider accepting it as the answer?